# Как создать ярлык с параметром быстрого запуска комбинацией клавиш?

Tags: delphi

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Delphi можно создать ярлык с параметром быстрого запуска комбинацией клавиш?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу, вот аналогичный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688235/how-can-i-set-a-hot-key-winkey-combination-to-call-an-application) на Stackoverflow. Копипаста:

```
uses ComObj, ActiveX, ShlObj):
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IObject: IUnknown;
  ISLink: IShellLink;
  IPFile: IPersistFile;
const
  HOTKEY_CONTROL = 512;
  HOTKEY_ALT = 1024;
begin
  // Creates a shell link (*.lnk) to C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe in the directory of this exe;
  // the link has keyboard shortcut CTRL+ALT+N.
  IObject := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
  ISLink := IObject as IShellLink;
  IPFile := IObject as IPersistFile;
  ISLink.SetPath('C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe');
  ISLink.SetHotkey(Ord('N') + HOTKEY_CONTROL + HOTKEY_ALT);
  IPFile.Save(PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Shortcut to Notepad.lnk'), false);
end;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё прекрасно работает!